# Render DevExpress XtraReport template as HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress, xtrareport

We are using DevExpress DX.10.2.  Our client has asked to be able to view the XtraReport templates (not the report itself, just the template) within an MVC 3 application that we maintain for them.

My first thought was that I'd have to fake the data to look like the "template" and show the actual reports.  However, I noticed in Visual Studio that the XtraReport designer has an "HTML View" option that renders the template in HTML.

I would think that if DevExpress is able to render the template as HTML in the designer then it's likely that there's a way to extract that HTML to render on a view.  Is there a way to extract HTML from an XtraReport template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stumbled across the solution.  Had to add a reference to DevExpress.XtraReports.Web and then the following line writes the report HTML to the response stream:

```
XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1();
DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.ReportViewer.WriteHtmlTo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response, report);
```